# Custom Validation in Parsley.js

Tags: parsley.js

Which parsley.js functions do I need to call to custom validate with javascript?

The reason I ask this is because I defined the following Assert Array in the back end and want to reuse this in the front end:
[ new Assert().Length( { min: 33, max: 25 } ), new Assert().NotBlank() ]

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'll find here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft) the documentation on how to define your custom validators for Parsley.

What you are trying to do may look something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  validators: {
    myvalidator: {
      fn: function (value) {
        return Validator.validate(value, [ new Assert().Length( { min: 33, max: 25 } ), new Assert().NotBlank() ]);
      },
      priority: 32
    }
  },
  i18n: {
    en: {
      myvalidator: 'Your field is invalid, or some different message'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Note: why defining these two asserts? NotBlank() is redundant with previous one, because a Blank field would obviously be wrong, its length being inferior to 33 min length. I don't really see the point to add NotBlank() here :)

Best

Comment: I agree noBlank doesn't make sense :) but I was just trying to have a composite validation. I'm trying to define validation rules in a db that can be reused in node.js and browser.
Your solution works but forces me to have duplicate errormessage if I have only one Assert [new Assert().Length( { min: 33, max: 25 } )]
Can default length error message be reused somehow? (I am looking in the code and the message is within validate method so maybe there is a way to pass in validation rules differently)